# How to render (appendChild) a raw DOMElement inside a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit:
Duplicate found: 
[How can I append external DOM to React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849219/how-can-i-append-external-dom-to-react-component)

---

So I can do something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = "http://blablabla";
  image.onload = () => {
    this.setState({ loaded: true });
    //do something;
  };
  this.image = image;
}

render() {
  if (this.state.loaded) {
    return toReactElement(this.image); // HOW TO DO THIS
  } else {
    return <Foo />
  }
}
```

What I was trying to do is to create an off-screen DOM object, like `new Image()`  (so you can get the dimensions of the picture or something like this), but do not `appendChild` it to any node.

Once it is loaded, use `appendChild` to add it to the page (usually after some extra calculation).

That's how I would do it without React. How can I do that in React?

Comment: Do you just need to know when the image finishes loading?

Comment: @Nitsew No. `Image.onload`, that's just an example. (Edited the question a little bit) I wanted to know how can I put a raw DOM element into a react Component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain of your specific use case, but I think what you might be looking for is the `onLoad` property.

```
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();

    this.state = {
      imageLoaded: false
    }
  }

  doSomething () {
    console.log('The image has finished loading.');

    this.setState({
      imageLoaded: true
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
       <img src='/test.png' onLoad={this.doSomething.bind(this)}>
    )
  }
}
```

There is also an `onError` property you might want to utilize in the event an image fails to load.

Comment: That is a little bit different. What I was trying to do is to create an off-screen `Image` object (from DOM API), but do not `appendChild` it to any node. Once it is loaded, use `appendChild` to add it to the page. That's what I want to do without React. How can I do that in React?

Comment: Soon I realized I can just give the `<img>` a `{display: none}` until it is loaded.