# ReactJS - render external DOM element with events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I use ReactJS 16.13.1 and now I want to render an external DOM element with its events.

So let's assume there is a

```html
<button type="button" id="testBtnSiri" onclick="alert('Functionality exists');">Testbutton Siri</button>
```

Which has been generated by a library (with some other events as well).

Now I want:
To copy it (with events) & render this element in my ReactJS render function.

What is the most appropriate way to do this ?

I am not looking for ReactDOM.createPortal().

**I want to show an external DOM element with its events in my React Component.**

Comment: This could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849219/how-can-i-append-external-dom-to-react-component

Comment: @yAzou no, this does not help. They render a React Component into another DOM element. I am looking for the exact opposite case. I want to show an external DOM element with its events in my ReactJS component.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper over `Node.addEventListener()` which will catch all the event listeners added to the button when it's rendered by other library. It could look like this(this code have to be executed before the external library creates the button):

```js
let ael = Node.prototype.addEventListener
let eventListeners = []
Node.prototype.addEventListener = function(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject | null, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void {
  if((this as HTMLElement).id === "buttonID")
    eventListeners.push({type, listener, options})
  this.addEventListener = ael
  this.addEventListener(type, listener, options)
}
```

Create react component with your button - you can create a new one, or inject using [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). Pass `eventListeners` array as a prop. On component mount and unmount, add/remove the event listeners to your button.

```
function ClonedButton({eventListeners}: any){
  useEffect(()=>{
    eventListeners.forEach((el) => document.getElementById("my-migrated-new-button")!.addEventListener(el.type, el.listener, el.options));
    return () => {
      eventListeners.forEach((el) => document.getElementById("my-migrated-new-button")!.removeEventListener(el.type, el.listener, el.options));
    }
  }, [])
  return <button id="my-migrated-new-button"></button>
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an idea. How would you then render the cloned element in ReactJS ?

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: @Gutelaunetyp I have provided examples using Typescript and react hooks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, yesterday I tried to clone the element using jQuery (with events) but already that did not work. Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731465/reactjs-open-upload-dialog-from-external-library ? There I also described my problem in a different, more general way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use HTML within your React code you need to make use of [`dangerouslySetInnelHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop on an element.

```
function libraryReturnedHTML() {
  return '<button type="button" id="testBtnSiri" onclick="alert('Functionality exists');">Testbutton Siri</button>'
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: libraryReturnedHTML} />;
}
```

However you must know that this makes your code susceptible to XSS attacks. In order to prevent such scenarios its a good idea to first **sanitize your HTML** so that you have only the desired scripts and link tags. In order to sanitizehtml you can simply use normal Javascript functions and [`document.createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker)

You can also make use of an existing library to sanitize your HTML. For example [`sanitize-html`](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html)
However the sanitization is just an added precaution.

Comment: This does not help me, as I need other functionality (events) that are on the button as well.

Comment: what kind of functionalities. They will all come with the scripts that the library provides you

Comment: A complete upload functionality and like 80 other events that I cannot rebuild manually.

Comment: As I said in the answer the events and other things should be provided by the library with the HTML returned by it

Comment: It does not help me at all. My ReactJS app is rendered after the external library and if I only use the html to render an identical button, the functionality (events) for the button won't be there.