# ReactJS - open upload dialog from external library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

It is a specific upload functionality that I need from an external library.

What I want to achieve is: open this external upload dialog if I click a button that is rendered by my ReactJS app.

I got a few ideas in mind:

1. Solution: Perform a synthetic click event on the "BS_WIDGET_INITIATOR" element if I click my ReactJS button (Tried that, did not work)
2. Solution: Clone that element by using ReactJS and render it (ugly)
3. Solution: Build the equivalent HTML in ReactJS and execute the script afterwards

I started with solution 3.

Here is the original integration of the external script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://blabla.de/js/widget.js">
  BS.CONFIG = {
    "token": "546bc22e-d747-421f-b4bf-b19b5129816b",
    "hostname": "https://blabla.de/match",
    "redirectOnError": "ERROR_PAGE",
    "postOriginalDocument": true,
    "images": {
      "dropbox": "https://www.blabla.de/dropbox.svg",
      "googledrive": "https://www.blabla.de/googledrive.svg",
      "onedrive": "https://www.blabla.de/onedrive.svg",
      "cv": "https://www.blabla.de/cv.svg"
    },
    "postProfileUrl": "LANDING_PAGE",
    "gapiClientId": "GOOGLE_API_WEBCLIENT_ID",
    "oneDriveApiKey": "ONEDRIVE_APP_KEY"
  }
</script>

<button id="BS_WIDGET_INITIATOR">Apply now</button>
<div id="BS_WIDGET_CONTAINER" style="display:none">
  Apply with
  <hr/>
  <div class="BS_WIDGET" rel="dropbox"></div>
  <div class="BS_WIDGET" rel="googledrive"></div>
  <div class="BS_WIDGET" rel="onedrive"></div>
  <hr id="BS_WIDGET_HYBRID_SEPARATOR" />
  <div class="BS_WIDGET" rel="cv"></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  #BS_WIDGET_CONTAINER {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  .BS_WIDGET {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  .BS_WIDGET[rel=cv],
  .BS_WIDGET[rel=form] {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  hr {
    border: solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  
  .BS_WIDGET:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .BS_WIDGET img[src$=".svg"] {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
  }
  
  .BS_WIDGET[rel=cv] img[src$=".svg"],
  .BS_WIDGET[rel=form] img[src$=".svg"] {
    width: auto;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="DROP-INS_API_KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onGapiLoad"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('picker', '1');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js" id="onedrive-js"></script>
```

Here is my ReactJS approach:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = (url) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = url;
    window.BS = {
      ...window.BS,
      CONFIG: {
            token: "546bc22e-d747-421f-b4bf-b19b5129816b",
            hostname: "https://blabla.de/match",
            redirectOnError: "ERROR_PAGE",
            postOriginalDocument: true,
            images: {
              dropbox: "https://www.blabla.de/dropbox.svg",
              googledrive: "https://www.blabla.de/googledrive.svg",
              onedrive: "https://www.blabla.de/onedrive.svg",
              cv: "https://www.blabla.de/cv.svg"
            },
            postProfileUrl: "LANDING_PAGE",
            gapiClientId: "GOOGLE_API_WEBCLIENT_ID",
            oneDriveApiKey: "ONEDRIVE_APP_KEY"
          }
      };
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import getTranslation from '../../utils/getTranslation';

import useScript from '../../utils/useScript';

const t = getTranslation;
const UploadButton = ({ uris, disabled }) => {
  if (uris && uris.BS) {
    useScript(uris.BS);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div id="BS_WIDGET_CONTAINER" style={{ display: 'none' }}>
        Apply with
        <hr />
        <div className="BS_WIDGET" rel="dropbox" />
        <div className="BS_WIDGET" rel="googledrive" />
        <div className="BS_WIDGET" rel="onedrive" />
        <hr id="BS_WIDGET_HYBRID_SEPARATOR" />
        <div className="BS_WIDGET" rel="cv" />
      </div>
      <Button id="BS_WIDGET_INITIATOR" disabled={disabled} type="primary">{t('upload-cv')}</Button>
    </>
  );
};
export default UploadButton;
```

But it seems, that the BS.CONFIG is not set properly. Is my way bad ? How can I achieve it ?

Comment: `properly` means is it there at all?

Comment: @MoshFeu no, it is not there

Comment: In useScript, If you useEffect on mount, and not only on change of the url will that help? Also In UploadButton call useScript after the component is mount.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using create-react-app, because this should not even compile. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

> "**React relies on the order in which Hooks are called.** [...] **This
>   is why Hooks must be called on the top level of our components.** If
>   we want to run an effect conditionally, we can put that condition
>   *inside* our Hook"

You need to move the condition into the useEffect hook.

---

On a slight tangent, custom hooks are best suited for effects that need to be run in various different components so you don't have to repeat yourself. (Something like a form validation perhaps?) This particular one's function is to append a pretty specific script to the document which I doubt you need to do more than once. You'd be better served moving the useEffect directly into the UploadButton component. Just a personal opinion though.

Also, React rendering can sometimes get slightly messy. Do you really want to remove the script when the user moves to page that unmounts the Upload button and then have it re-added and the script refetched when the button gets remounted? What happens when you have two UploadButtons on the page? The script gets called twice, is this an issue? In the original integration, I want to believe it only gets called once in the file, so maybe have a check for the script in the useEffect hook and bail if it already exists. However, this is also just speculation and perhaps you intended it to be as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the third solution is the best approach. As for the script execution, you should be able to just put that exact script tag in your `index.html`.